# Cannot store large values when calculating factorials

Tags: rust

I'm implementing an algorithm to get the factorial of a certain number for a programming class.

```
fn factorial(number: u64) -> u64 {
    if number < 2 {
        1
    } else {
        number * factorial(number - 1)
    }
}
```

When I tried with 100 or even with 25 I get this error `"thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow'"`, so I tried wrapping, and the result function was:

```
fn factorial(number: u64) -> u64 {
    if number < 2 {
        1
    } else {
        number.wrapping_mul(factorial(number - 1))
    }
}
```

This way there is not panic but the result is always zero, so I tried using f64 and result was

100! = 93326215443944100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

instead of

100! =  93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000

Is there another way to store the result so the right value is returned?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, I think I should note that the value you originally claimed for 100! was incorrect. How did you calculate that value?

Comment: @JasonWatkins c++ program but something went wrong apparently, thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

100! is a *really* big number. In fact, the largest factorial that will fit in a `u64` is just 20!. For numbers that don't fit in a `u64`, [`num::bigint::BigUint`](https://huonw.github.io/primal/num/bigint/struct.BigUint.html) is an appropriate storage option.

The following code calculates a value for 100!. You can run it in your browser [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=0d709ccaf80f0976ec04239e07e7e84f).

```
extern crate num;

use num::BigUint;

fn factorial(number: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    let big_1 = 1u32.into();
    let big_2 = 2u32.into();
    if number < big_2 {
        big_1
    } else {
        let prev_factorial = factorial(number.clone() - big_1);
        number * prev_factorial
    }
}

fn main() {
    let number = 100u32.into();
    println!("{}", factorial(number));
}
```

To give some insight into why `u64` doesn't work, you can call the `bits` method on the result. If you do so, you will find that the value of 100! requires **525** bits to store. That's more than 8 `u64`'s worth of storage.

Comment: Why don't you use `if number < big_2` etc.?

Comment: For some reason that wasn't working for me when I initially wrote the answer. Looks like it does work fine with the final version of the code, so I'll update the answer to use it.

Comment: Note that a tail-recursive version is better: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1705066

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to complement @Jason Watkins answer with an iterative solution using [`Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html):

```rust
extern crate num;

use num::{bigint::BigUint, One};

fn factorial(value: u32) -> BigUint {
    (2..=value).fold(BigUint::one(), |res, n| res * n)
}

fn main() {
    let result = factorial(10);
    assert_eq!(result, 3628800u32.into());
}
```